# Nondimensionalize Pendulum Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Equations for the dynamics of a pendulum:

$A=-a\sin(\theta)-bv$

$\theta(0)=\theta_0$, $\;v(0)=\omega_0$

where $\theta$ is the angle of the pendulum with respect to it's natural resting point, $v$ is the angular velocity, and $A$ is the angular acceleration (not to be confused with $a$, which is just a constant).

I am trying to nondimensionalize the system and choose two sets of characteristic scales such that one is for short term and one is for long term behavior.

I know the steps I need to take are the following:

1. express variables in characteristic scale
2. substitute variables with scales into equation
3. divide the equation by the product of the scales
4. simplify to make dimensionless
5. identify scales that make terms as simple as possible

I know the main goal is to find the dimensions of each variable and then define new variables from the products of variables with equal dimension but I just can't seem to get it

Comment: Is $A$ is second derivative term of something?

Comment: All I am told is that $A$ is the angular acceleration